# Getting point data (structure names) onto line segments and create to/from attribute in line segment?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, utility-network

I have two shapefiles, one being line segments (gravity sewer) and another being points (manholes). I want to be able to show to and from in the line attribute table.

Is there an easy work around to this rather than editing each line segment manually?

I currently have Arc10.2 but I am upgrading shortly.

Answer (score 4):

Esri's [Attribute Assistant](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/) can do this for you.  You can create rules for calculations to be automatically run, including copying values from end-point features onto a line (upstream/downstream manholes onto pipes).

Look at the [From Junction Field](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#from-junction-field) and the [To Junction Field](http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/documentation/methods-all-methods/#to-junction-field) methods.

The Attribute Assistant can take a bit of setting up, but read the documentation - it's very good - and you'll find it's actually not too difficult to get up and running.